# Google Line Chart: How to add units?

Tags: google-visualization

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Example

How can I add units to the vertical axis like "$" or "€"? In the example, it should be 1.200 $, 1.000 $, 800 $, 600 $ and 400 $.

Just adding '$' like this doesn't work:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000 '$',      400],
      ['2005',  1170 '$',      460],
      ['2006',  660 '$',       1120],
      ['2007',  1030 '$',      540]
    ]);
```

I know, it's a bad example as sales doesn't have any unit, but it's just an example.

Comment: Please have a look on my topic at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532342/how-to-change-the-format-type-of-the-label-in-google-chart-with-javascript/24537837#24537837

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add a format tag to your graph options as follows:

```
var options = {
    vAxis: {format:'# $'}
};
```

Reference: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! Do you also know, how to apply this format tag to the tooltips?

Comment: Thanks, and use `0` instead of `#` if you don't want 0 values to show as completely blank.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled onto this question and found that the newer Google Sheets (2017) has an "Advanced Edit" option for Grids/Charts. Click the down arrow in the upper-right, and you'll see it. The last tab on that interface lets you set custom prefix/suffix for data Axes if you scroll down.