# How to change the format type of the label in Google Chart with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change the format type of the label in Google Chart with Javascript as my image below:

**Here is my data (in US Dollars):**

```
      ['2004',  340456060],
      ['2005',  581766089],
      ['2006',  666099879],
      ['2007',  1980361212],
```

**1.  When the chart runs, I would like to modify these figures with `,`. Hence, whenever the mouseover, it must be like that:**

- 2007 with Sales: 1,980,361,212
- 2006 with Sales: 666,099,879
- 2005 with Sales: 581,766,089
- 2004 with Sales: 340,456,060

**2.  How to add `$` as the last character?**

- 2007 with Sales: 1,980,361,212$
- 2006 with Sales: 666,099,879$
- 2005 with Sales: 581,766,089$
- 2004 with Sales: 340,456,060$

**3.  Besides that, how to change the label to `%`?**

- 2007 with Sales: 55.6%
- 2006 with Sales: 18.6%
- 2005 with Sales: 16.3%
- 2004 with Sales: 9.5%

[image: Pic]

---

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7p5cK/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales'],
          ['2004',  340456060],
          ['2005',  581766089],
          ['2006',  666099879],
          ['2007',  1980361212]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            vAxis: {title: 'Dollars'},
            hAxis: {title: 'Year'}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15327216/3565383

Comment: @reaxis: I got the same with Ben's question. How can I apply this format tag to the tooltips?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer. I just add the highlight code. Please let me know if something goes wrong.

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,###$'
});
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/7p5cK/1/)</kbd>**

Comment: Any idea how you can add a unit without interacting with the number of decimals?

Answer (score 0):

**Worked...**

my final Script

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
pattern: '\n#,###.00 $'
});

formatter.format(data, 1);
formatter.format(data, 2);
formatter.format(data, 3);
```

I add for another data 2 and data 3 bar plus (.00) for 2 decimal format